# Should I put Copyright Notice on my content before I submit for copyright?

Tags: copyright

I am from India and I have made some computer information based videos.
I am going to sell them soon. Well, my problem is I have put a copyright notice while making the production of the videos.

Like a label at the footer of the entire video. Here's an example:

> © 2016 Produced By *MY NAME*, All Rights Reserved

Well, once I complete the video,  I am going to to submit it for copyright.

Is that OK to put copyright notice before submitting for copyright or will there be an issue?

Answer (score 1):

Under most countries' copyright laws, the copyright exists as soon as a work is created.  The copyright generally becomes enforceable upon registration of the copyright.  Most works that are marked "© 2016" have not actually had their copyright registered at the time the copyright mark is embedded in the work.

Comment: In most jurisdictions copyrights are also enforceable without registration. The registration just makes it simpler.

Comment: So is this ok to put copyright caption on it ? Is there any issue while submitting the video with that caption ?